# Почему возникает ошибка в верстка почтовых шаблонов для Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Сделали верстку для шаблонов писем к почтовым событиям. Сохранили ее в виде темы для почтовых сообщений в разделе  **Настройки->Настройки продукта->Почтовые события->Темы оформления**

Возникла проблема, когда письмо приходит на почту то верстка не правильно отображается. Битрикс при генерации письма берет все CSS-стили из раздела header и добавляет их в атрибут style html-тегов верстки. Часть тегов вообще оказалась продублирована. В итоге верстка поехала. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это связано с тем что вёрстка писем это отдельный процесс и лючше пользоваться инлайновыми стилями. И не использовать сложной вёрстки — пользоваться желательно по старинке таблицами